# Postgres Fastest way to compare arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql

In a stored procedure, I am generating an array of keys and want to compare it to an array of keys off a table.  What is the fastest way to compare two arrays to see if both of them have at least one value that matches?

So far, we've tried the following:

- Loop over the generated keys and compare them to the key field (slow)
- Use array operation overlap (&&) on the arrays

Here is the definition of table: `solicitation`

```
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regclass),
type_id bigint,
name character varying(2000),
key character varying[],
status bigint
```

Sample Code from Stored Procedure

```
-- keys = list of generated keys
FOR _id, _name, _type IN
   SELECT rec.eid, rec.domain, rec.name, rec.type_id
   from   solicitation rec 
   where  rec.key && _keys
   and    rec.status in (1201, 1202, 1241)
LOOP
...
END LOOP;
```

`key` is indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the array overlap operation (&&) was fast but the slow down was due to NULLs in the generated array.

Stripping out the NULLs increased the performance from 6 seconds to 300 milliseconds for a table size in the millions.

Answer (score 1):

Array operators in postgresql are pretty fast.

But note that you should use `GIN` index to gain performance improvement.

Most of times, doing jobs in DB server is faster in performance, but note that if your database server is overloaded, creating replicas of web servers is more easy that creating database replicas, so try to move load from DB-servers to web-servers, to better manage load across web servers.

Comment: We're using a GIN index already.  The issue turned out that the generated array of keys had NULLs in them which slowed down the performance tremendously.

Comment: So, strip down NULLs from arrays when writing to Database